# Class Design - Return subclass from base class initalization

Tags: python

I have two classes, with similar methods (`read`, `write`, `insert`) but because of the file types the produce, their methods must be implemented differently. Ideally, I would like the user to initialize a base type and the appropriate subtype is returned based on keywords during instantiation:

```
c = SomeThing() # returns subclass of type 1 (set in default)
c = Something(flag=True) # returns the other subclass
```

Initially I tried putting a return statement in the `__init__` of the base class, but appparently `__init__` should return None, so not sure where to set this; should I just create a base class factory method that returns the appropriate type?:

```
class SomeThing:
    def __init__(self, flag=False):
        self.build(flag)
    def build(self, flag):
        if not flag:
            return SubclassOne()
        reutnr SubclassTwo()
```

Or is there a better way for dynamically binding the appropriate methods based on keywords passed at instantiation? I wouldnt think this would be ideal:

```
class SomeThing:
    def __init__(self, flag=False):
        if not flag:
            setattr(self, 'write', self.write_one)
        else:
            setattr(self, 'write', self.write_two)
    def write_one(self):
        # stuff
    def write_two(self):
        # stuff
```

Because the user of the interface could simply access the other methods, and I wouldnt want to define each method outside the classes because then the user could say do `from something import write_one` which would be inappropriate behavior.

Comment: @AndyG I thought about creating a factory function, that is one way. However there are some attributes that the classes inherit from the base, so I think it makes sense to define a base.

Comment: What you want is technically possible I believe, but it's going to lead to some hard to read, hard to extend, possibly buggy code.

Comment: @AndyG You think? I would've guessed that if a user inspects the interface and see that by calling `c = SomeThing()` they would see that that `self.build()` is called at initialization, then jumps down the method that returns.

Comment: `__new__` is a "return-able" version of `__init__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you go with a factory of sorts:

```
class Base(object):
    # ...

class SomeThing(Base):
    # ...

class OtherThing(Base):
    # ...

def create_thing(flag = False):
    if flag:
        return SomeThing()
    else:
        return OtherThing()
```